# asp.net core 2.2 brotli compression not working on IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, compression, brotli

I read in Asp.Net Core 2.2 documentation, [brotli compression is added to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

I have `app.UseResponseCompression();` and `services.AddResponseCompression();` in my `Startup.cs` but when I tried it on my system with latest Chrome browser, I see only gzip compression at response headers. I host my Asp.Net Core 2.2 app on Windows Server 2012 IIS web server.

What should I config to get working brotli compression?

[image: dev tools screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're hosting in IIS then that means IIS is the webserver that's communicating with the browser. It sits in front of your ASP.NET Core app and proxies all requests and responses, but it doesn't support Brotli by default.

You need to configure response compression with IIS. There's an extension available for adding Brotli and Zlib support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview

You can also run your ASP.NET Core app without IIS.

Comment: Oh I found the exact url: https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2016/03/iis-brotli Thank you!

Comment: I'll note that the approach OP attempts is possible, albeit not recommended.  It's just a choice of whether you want to rely on compression middleware running within the application rather than compression running as a server module (this suggestion).  That being said, the documentation OP links to recommends the server module approach to improve performance.  The secondary benefit of the server module approach is that it tends to provide out-of-the-box support for caching compressed responses for static content.

Comment: Having tested it out, I'll note that the tertiary benefit of the server module approach is that it's turnkey.

Comment: I use this solution, but I found I have to remove the gzip scheme, otherwise, it always uses gzip, any better solution?

Comment: @Leon Brotli is widely supported now, you can leave gzip off: https://caniuse.com/?search=brotli

Comment: @ManiGandham - Thanks so much, I agree with leaving gzip.
But just in case anyone wants to keep both br and gzip schemes and they use older IIS version(<10), I found a solution:
Except the rewrite rule described in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/using-iis-compression#before-iis-100-version-1803, we have to click "Unlock section" on "system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables" section on IIS "Configuration Editor" to make the rewrite rule working.

For the case use IIS version 10 and above, doesn't need to do this trick.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that your application is hosted in IIS and it says in the link you attached

> Use Response Compression Middleware when you're unable to use IIS
> Dynamic Compression Module

So if you use IIS you can remove that middleware and use the out of the box IIS Compression module.

The steps you need to take are:

1. Install brotli on your webserver - just follow the instructions here
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview#installing-iis-compression%5D
2. Remove the compression middleware
3. On your applicationHost.conf make sure that `brotli` exist under `gzip`
4. Comment out the `gzip` option in `applicationHost.conf` because 98% of the browsers support `brotli` compression and in old version of IIS `gzip` is selected instead of `brotli` because of the order in the `Request Header` (e.g `gzip deflate br`).